# How do I get rid of the last tr td bottom border using css?

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

How can I get rid of the last table row bottom border using CSS? I have used color coding on the HTML page to identify which border belong to what. I can see that the bottom border needs to be removed as it is clashing with my container border:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

/* ----- Scrolling Table ----- */
.dataGridHeader {
position:relative;
padding-top:24px;
_padding-top:23px;

width:895px;

border-left: 1px solid red;
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

.dataGridContent {
overflow:auto;
width:915px;
height:144px;
}

.dataGridHeader thead tr {
width:915px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

.dataGridHeader table thead tr th, .dataGridHeader table tbody tr td { 
text-align:left;
height:0;
}

table.scrolltablestyle {
border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

table.scrolltablestyle tbody tr td{
    background: #fff;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
table.scrolltablestyle thead tr th{
background-color: #FFFFD9;
font-weight: normal;
text-align:left;
padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}

table.scrolltablestyle thead tr th {
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

table.scrolltablestyle tbody tr td{
    border-right: 1px solid green;
}




</style>



</head>
<body>

<div class="dataGridHeader">
  <div class="dataGridContent">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scrolltablestyle style-even">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="160">Shopper Name</th>
          <th width="160">First Name</th>
          <th width="160">Last Name</th>
          <th width="160">User ID</th>
          <th width="160">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">John</td>
    <td width="160">Doe</td>
    <td width="160">C2C Fishing</td>
    <td width="160">Enabled</td>
  </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this

```
table.scrolltablestyle tr:last-child td
{
border-bottom:none;
}
```

Or you can just set as like this

```
table.scrolltablestyle tr:last-child td
{
border-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: `border-bottom:none` applies to border styling. You better use `border-bottom:0`

Comment: thanks @otinanai for your suggestion, i have added that option in my answer and updated my post. :)

Comment: Sachin, still doesn't work. Is there perhaps something overriding it? I'm using IE7 at work.

Comment: @JohnSmith it should work. I have seen it on my machine on simple html page. is there any way like live url or anything by which you can show me your html code so that i can figure it out what's wrong with that otherwise it's perfect with your above code.

Comment: CSS selector `:last-child` is compatible only to modern browsers and IE9 and up. See a reference here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp . But really... who develops for IE7 any more!?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line-:

```
 border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
```